# How to return a value from a foreach loop of a collection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two classes `Invoice` and `InvoiceProducts`. `InvoiceProducts` is a collection and has a get only property called `Price` and I want `Invoice` to have a property called `TotalPrice` which would return the `Price` foreach item in the `InvoiceProducts` collections added to it. However I'm not sure about going about this. With the current way I'm trying to use it I get an error saying

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Is there a way to do this?

Current way:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int InvoiceID { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;
    private decimal totalPrice;
    public decimal TotalPrice {
        get
        {
            return totalPrice;
        }
        set
        {
            foreach(var item in InvoiceProducts)
            {
                totalPrice += item.Price;
            }
        }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceProducts> InvoiceProducts { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceProducts
{
    public int InvoiceProductsID { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int ProductQuantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get { return Product.ProductPrice * ProductQuantity; } }

    public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Add init for InvoiceProducts (eg public virtual ICollection<InvoiceProducts> InvoiceProducts { get; set; } = new List<InvoiceProducts>();)

Comment: You also can delete set part for TotalPrice and use only get (of course calculating the answer before return)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public decimal TotalPrice {
    get
    {
        return InvoiceProducts.Sum(product => product.Price);
    }
}
```

or shorter, because it's get only:

```
public decimal TotalPrice => InvoiceProducts.Sum(product => product.Price);
```

And of course you need to initialize your list of products and probably make it get only.

```
public Invoice() 
{
    InvoiceProducts = new List<InvoiceProcuct>();
}

public ICollection<InvoiceProduct> InvoiceProducts { get; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is already answered, but I wanted to provide some additional clarification, if I might try.  A `set` takes parameters, and is special logic that you want to run whenever you assign the value of a property, based on what you're assigning it to.  To take a simple example:

```
  public class SpecialNumber
    {
        private double _theNumber; 

        public double TheNumber
        {
            get { return _theNumber; }
            set
            {
                _theNumber = value * Math.PI;
            }
        }
    }
```

The reserved word `value` is the right-hand-side of the expression:

```
specialNumberObject.TheNumber = 5.0;
```

As such, value will take on 5.0 inside the setter.  The logic you had inside your setter as indicated by S. Spindler is perfect for a `get`, since it defines a **custom return** that you want to have executed whenever we want to **access** the value of a property.

Another version of my class might decide to have a property that multiplies by PI on the way out, which might be useful if the back-end logic in my class relied on the number being its' unmultiplied form.  In that case, the logic would be more appropriate for a getter.

I hope I didn't confuse the issue.